# How can I receive a notification/event when mediaStreamTrack.enabled is modified?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediastreamsource

I am using `getUserMedia` to get access to web cam. I have a function which toggle on and off the video doing the following:

```
  var videoTracks = this.stream.getVideoTracks();
  if (videoTracks.length === 0) {
    trace('No local video available.');
    return;
  }

  trace('Toggling video mute state.');
  for (var i = 0; i < videoTracks.length; ++i) {
    videoTracks[i].enabled = !videoTracks[i].enabled;
  }

  trace('Video ' + (videoTracks[0].enabled ? 'unmuted.' : 'muted.'));
```

How can receive an event when the the value of `enabled` is changed? I tried to use `Object.observe`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell there currently is no event fired/callback invoked when the `enabled` property changes.

From [here](http://muaz-khan.blogspot.co.at/2014/05/webrtc-tips-tricks.html):

> Also, there is no "onmuted" and "onunmuted" event defined or fired in the WebRTC native implementations.

You might have to build this mechanism yourself:

> Keep in mind that you're disabling a media track locally; it will not fire any event on target users side. If you disabled video track; then it will cause "blank-video" on target-users side.
>
> You can manually fire events like "onmuted" or "onmediatrackdisabled" by using socket that was used for signaling. You can send/emit messages like:

```
yourSignalingSocket.send({
    isMediaStreamTrackDisabled: true,
    mediaStreamLabel: stream.label
});
```

According to the [spec](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/archives/20131017/getusermedia.html#widl-MediaStreamTrack-onunmute) this should be part of the MediaStreamTrack interface eventually:

> onmute of type EventHandler,
>
> This event handler, of type mute, must be supported by all objects implementing the MediaStreamTrack interface.

I tried assigning a function to a track's `onmute` in Chrome (43) but it never got called ([looks like this is not implemented yet](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=405520&q=onmute&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)).